# PHP array_intersect case-insensitive and ignoring tildes

Tags: php, string-comparison, case-insensitive, array-intersect

Is there any function similar to "array_intersect" but it is in mode case-insensitive and ignoring tildes?

The array_intersect PHP function compares array elements with === so I do not get the expected result.

For example, I want this code :

```
$array1 = array("a" => "gréen", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Outputs **gréen** and **red**. In default array_intersect function just **red** is proposed (normal cause ===).

Any solution ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php

function to_lower_and_without_tildes($str,$encoding="UTF-8") {
  $str = preg_replace('/&([^;])[^;]*;/',"$1",htmlentities(mb_strtolower($str,$encoding),null,$encoding));
  return $str;
}

function compare_function($a,$b) {
  return strcmp(to_lower_and_without_tildes($a), to_lower_and_without_tildes($b));
}

$array1 = array("a" => "gréen", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_uintersect($array1, $array2,"compare_function");
print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => gréen
    [0] => red
)
```

Comment: I know it is an old topic, but there is an error in this function, that causes it to miss some matching keys. Actually, running the exact same code as presented in this answer on PHP 7.1.23, I get as result only "red". The reason for that is that the comparison function `compare_function` should return -1, 0 or 1, depending on whether `$a` is <, =, or > than `$b`, respectively. To fix this `return strcmp(to_lower_and_without_tildes($a), to_lower_and_without_tildes($b));` should be used.

Comment: I edited the answer to incorporate @ThiagoBarcala's comment, as the answer in its previous state was not fully correct

Answer (score 17):

```
$result = array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', $array1), array_map('strtolower', $array2));
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that it should also ignore the tildes. Anyway your solution is correct for case-insensitive.

Comment: this only works if the result can be lowercase, not if for example, the first array is all upper and the second is lower but the result need to upper

Comment: @DarkMukke Here is no problem at all. Just replace `'strtolower'` with `'strtoupper'` and you'll get the result in uppercase

Comment: @hindmost so what happens if you code this function as a helper method in a framework where you don't know what if its going to be uppercase, lowercase or mixed ?

Comment: this returns the strtolower-ed values instead of the original ones; the accepted answer returns the correct values