# how to compare two arrays (case insensitive) in php

Tags: php, comparison

I want to know how to compare 2 arrays in PHP for matches. I've used `array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)`. I want the matches to be case insensitive.

**Example:**

```
$arr1 = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'];
$arr2 = ['Hello', 'fine', 'You'];
```

**Expected Output**

```
['hello','you']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the result can be in all lowercase, you can do it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21701044/688161):

```
$result = array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', $arr1), array_map('strtolower', $arr2));
```

Otherwise, you can use [`array_uintersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) which takes a callback for the string comparison. You can then use [`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) for case insensitive string comparison.

```
$result = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, "strcasecmp");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this quite simply by passing both arrays through `array_map()` in order to `strtolower()` (or `strtoupper()`) them first:

```
$arr1 = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'];
$arr2 = ['Hello', 'fine', 'You'];

var_dump(
    array_intersect(
        array_map('strtolower', $arr1),
        array_map('strtolower', $arr2)
    )
);

// [ "hello", "you" ]
```